# sending a extra parameter in .submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

hello I have a function where I am using ajax to try to do get some value and then submit a php form which looks like this.

```
/* form-horizontal */
    $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "register_form");

    if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
    {
        if ($_SESSION['login'] == 'DoBusinessPerformed' || $_SESSION['login'] == 'NormalPerformed') {                
            echo form_open('myprofile/ManageProcessNew/'.$pathName, $attributes);
        } else {
            echo form_open('myprofile/RegisterProcessNew/'.$pathName, $attributes);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo form_open('myprofile/RegisterProcessNew/'.$pathName, $attributes); 
    }
```

As you can see i have a .$pathname which is the parameter which contains the value 'borrow' and here is the ajax function which I am calling to send this form.

```
 self.checkMangoPayId = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/checkMangoPayID/' + auth,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
               if(data.mangopay_id == null){
                   alert("going to save page for mango id");
                   // here is where I submit the form
                   $("#register_form").submit();
               }else{
                   self.mangoPayIdCheck(true);
                   self.showModalAddId();

               }
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error code thrown: " + errorThrown);
            })
            .always(function(data){

            });
        }
```

what I want to do is in the .submit function add a way to change the value of .$path name and put borrowed instead of borrow.

I tried a lot of ways like .submit(borrowed), but non of those ways work, so basically all I want to send a different value inside pathname to my controller which receives this parameter.

Comment: I don't _really_ understand what you're trying to do. But if you're trying to send an extra field as part of the form, then you could add a hidden field to the HTML form and set its value before ajaxing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just before your submit you can add a attribute like this

```
$("#register_form").attr('action',BASEURL + "index.php/bla/bla/borrowed");
```

and then when you submit it will attach it at the back as parameter.